# Tasks in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to run a task from a task in VSCode?

Example json:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Show In Chrome",
        "windows": {
            "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
        },
        "osx": {
            "command": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
        },
        "args": [
            "${file}"
        ],
        "type": "process",
    },
    {
        "taskName": "Show Coverage",
        // this is the task to call another task
    }
]
```

}

What i would like to do is have the Show Coverage task look for a file in the coverage folder and then call Show In Chrome task to show it as the arguments of that file being passed.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the current config from the docs website isn't updated for tasks.

However if you want a task to call other tasks because it depends on them you can simply add this configuration

```
    {
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Show In Chrome",
        "identifier": "showInChrome",
        "windows": {
            "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
        },
        "osx": {
            "command": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
        },
        "args": [
            "${file}"
        ],
        "type": "process",
    },
    {
        "taskName": "Show Coverage",
        "dependsOn": "showInChrome"
    }
]
}
```

this will cause the task to run the previous task and then run whatever commands it has set as well.

Note:  you can use multiple depends by using an array of identifiers.